# Configuration management nodes in azure

Tags: azure, configuration, automation

Viewing the pricing information for Azure automation under Configuration management  is lists nodes? What are these? In partciualr Non-Azure nodes I can't work it out from the context

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/pricing/details/automation/

Answer (score 0):

Configuration management is Azure DSC Pull Server as a service. You are charged per node that is connected to the service and pulling configuration from the pull server. You can connect Azure, or non-Azure nodes.